# save multiple plots r into separate jpg

Tags: r, plot, sjplot

Dear Stackoverflow'ers!

I have simple database, app. 130 variables, 1500 records and lots of similar plots to create. I try to avoid save them by hand. The for loop works perfectly for plots (in RStudio).

[Here are the data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rts3zhwlta2t3ou/data.csv?dl=0) as .csv on dropbox.

```
data <- read.csv2("data.csv", header=TRUE)
data <- select(data,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7)

for (i in data) {
    sjp.frq(i)
}
```

I would like to save the plots in some directory as a separate .png or .jpg files. I found some clues [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/automatically-save-your-plots-to-a-folder-2/). The code looks like this:

```
data <- select(df,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7)
variables <- names(data)

for (i in data) {
  png(paste0("plots/plot_",names(data)[i],".png"))
    sjp.frq(i)
  dev.off()
}
```

I deliberately simplified the sjp.frq expression to not make the code unnessecarely complicated.

And here's the problem. I get only single .png file in folder. Where do I make mistake? There should be seven of them.

Best regards, MaciejB.

PS. I follow the suggestion of making code reproducible and added sample of my databaase. When I use i.e. iris, it works. It seems to be something wrong with my data, some NA's maybe? But when I used na.omit() it's the same.

PS.2 I checked another ploting functions like hist() or plot() but it's the same. Only one plot produced and saved.

Comment: Please try to make your code reproducible. For example, make some plots using `iris` or `mtcars`. Without reproducible code we can only guess at what's happening.

Comment: Thanks, it's done. I added the original dataset and corrected 'dane'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works here!

```
data1 <- read.csv2("~/Temp/data.csv", header=TRUE)
data <- select(data1,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7)
variables <- names(data)
dane=1:length(variables)
for (i in dane ) { #i=2
  png(paste0("Temp/plot_",names(data)[i],".png"))
  sjp.frq(data[,i],title = names(data)[i])
  dev.off()
}
```

Here 3 of all plots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Now we are talking! ;) Thanks a lot. It worked for me too ;) Could you write me few words of explanation. Am I correct that loop parameters were wrong? Especially naming/recalling the variables?

Comment: I think the problem is in naming the files. In your code the `i` takes the hole column, then the `paste0` will gave you a vector of strings instead of one string to name of the file.