# R png() Function Adding Extra Stuff to Filenames and Ignoring Image Size Flags

Tags: r, save, png

I have an R script working and it is nearly done but there is one final problem. I am using the png(filename = " ", width = N, height = M, units =" ", ...) function in R but it is appending the width, height, and units flags to the png filenames. I can't find a way in the default help to fix this.

The exact command I am using is

```
 for(i in 1:length(lst)){
 
 png(paste0(filename = paste( lst[i]), ".png", width = 1280, height = 688, units = "px"))
 
 ...all plotting code...

 dev.off()

 }
```

Where `lst[i]` a list of filenames read through a loop. I end up with the .png files being called

idq27qecq.png1280688px where 1280688px is the stuff I ***dont want*** in the name. The png files are also all ***incorrectly sized***, and have a size of 480 by 480 pixels.

How can I fix this?

If I remove the paste0 at the beginning I get the error

> Error in png(filename = paste(lst[i]), ".png", width = 1280, height = 688,  :
> invalid 'pointsize' argument

and also

> In png(filename = paste(lst[i]), ".png", width = 1280, height = 688,  :
> NAs introduced by coercion

Any help fixing the names and sizes of my output images would be helpful.
I looked at this post
[save multiple plots r into separate jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746151/save-multiple-plots-r-into-separate-jpg)
but it did not work even though I tried to implement it.

All of this is being done in the Rstudio engine through a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `paste0` is not needed, also the second `paste` should be used only to create `filename` value. Try :

```
for(i in 1:length(lst)){
  png(filename = paste(lst[i], ".png"), width = 1280, height = 688, units = "px")
  #  
  #...all plotting code...
  #
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works, I am relatively new to R this helps a lot